# Can I use Ubuntu Desktop to provision my own computer's resources?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Can I use Ubuntu Desktop to provision my own computer's resources using KVM for VT-X?

Or do I need the Ubuntu Server version?
I am confused about the difference between them.

Please help.

Comment: You might wish to review [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM)

Comment: So KVM only works with the Server Version? Not the Desktop?

Comment: I haven't tested as I use virtualbox for VM's on my desktop. Have you tried it? What happened when you did?

Comment: It seems that VMs don't support KVM because they are virtual and not in a direct contact with the hardware. That's why I'm aiming to partition my computer to install an actual Linux to use KVM. Now I'm just wondering if I shall install the Desktop or the Server version of it.

Comment: as I said I haven't tested it. The docs appear to suggest using the server version.